# What does escapting a forward slash in regex have no effect?

Tags: python, regex

When I run these lines in a python console

```
from re import match
    
temp = "THIS/THAT"
match("^[A-Z]+/[A-Z]+$", temp)
match("^[A-Z]+\/[A-Z]+$", temp)
```

Both matches print out

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='THIS/THAT'>
```

Why the backslash (or escaped forward slash) have no effect on the results?

Comment: `/` is not any special regex metacharacter, `\/`  = `/`. Your patterns are equal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So why is there no impact from escaping a non-special character

Comment: It is not an alphanumeric char, escaping a non-alnum char makes it match itself. `\,` matches the same way as `,`. Note that beginning with Python 3.6 "unknown escapes consisting of '\' and an ASCII letter now are errors." However, `/` is not a letter, you can escape it, but you do not have to.

Comment: What did you think it would do?